# In Python, what's the method for returning only the max odd integer in a list?

Tags: python, list

If you have a list of numbers, how do you return only the max odd integer **without** using the `max()` function?

I'm assuming it will have something to do with `int % 2 != 0`, but I'm not sure what else.

---

I also have to return the overall max integer without using max(), but I got around that by sorting my list and using `list[-1]`.

Comment: I assume this is homework so I will give you some hints only..

Comment: sorting the list is not optimized, you should better try a loop with a conditional

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the great comments and answers.  I was able to get something that worked for my assignment.

Answer (score 4):

```
max(i for i in my_list if i % 2)
```

---

Edit: without `max()`:

```
def highest_odd(seq):
    """
    Return the highest odd number in `seq`.
    If there are no odd numbers, then return `None`.

    """
    for i in sorted(seq, reverse=True):
        if i % 2:
            return i
```

Comment: The best solution, however it is homework and I don't think he is allowed to use the max function. He could create his own max function and then use your solution however.

Comment: I'd implement my own max function (really not hard) and use the first solution - clearly the best here. No additional memory overhead and we don't sort the list..

Comment: I'm fairly certain that making a separate function that uses the max function defeats the purpose of my assignment.

Comment: `max()` can be implemented in linear time (actually in one pass), constant space, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9185669/4279). But `sorted()` is `O(n*log(n))` in time and `O(n)` in space. In practice it doesn't matter for a small lists, but in practice you would use `max()` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Logic:

1. make a local variable for the maximum odd number found so far, and initialise it to something sensible.
2. iterate through your list, checking if a number is odd.
3. if it is odd, also check if it is larger than the maximum odd number found so far.
4. if both 2 and 3 were true, update the maximum odd number found so far to the current element.
5. after completing the loop, double check that the number *has* been updated from your sensible default value.  this should give you some idea about what a "sensible default" should and shouldn't be for step 1.

`

```
>>> mylist = [-10, -11, 4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 3]
>>> maxodd = None   # note: this will compare less than any integer
>>> for number in mylist:
...   if number % 2 and number > maxodd:
...     maxodd = number
... 
>>> 
>>> if maxodd is None:
...   raise StandardError('There were no odd integers in {}'.format(mylist))
... 
>>> print maxodd
7
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at 'filter' built-in function

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [-10, -11, 4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 3]
if any(i%2==1 for i in mylist):
    _max=reduce(lambda i,j:i if i>j else j,(i for i in mylist if i%2==1))
else:
    _max=None
print _max
```

Comment: you don't need to iterate twice over the list. Here's an [algorithm that accepts any iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9186807/4279).

Comment: Nice solution mate. btw this doesn't iterate over the whole list twice, although it does go over all the initial even numbers twice. (any() pull out when it finds something). Originally I didn't do this check so it was a one line solution. Reduce would give an error if you gave an invalid iterable however.

Comment: it iterates "twice" in a sense that it won't work for iterators, [example](http://ideone.com/u9zDZ), but indeed it consumes `2*N` elements only in the worst case (all even except the last one) e.g., `[2,4,88,10,3]`.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. Yeah that's handy in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to [@robert king's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185959/4279) (for your homework something like [@wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185669/4279) is more suited):

```
def maxodd(iterable):
    """Return largest odd item in the iterable or None if all items are even."""
    odd = (n for n in iterable if n % 2)
    max_ = next(odd, None)
    if max_ is not None:
       return reduce(lambda n,m: n if n > m else m, odd, max_)
```

It is a one-pass algorithm so it accepts any iterable.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/u9zDZ)

```
print(maxodd([-10, -11, 4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 3])) # -> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l=[3,8,2,1,5,6]
>>> l_odd=[i for i in l if i%2==1]
>>> l_odd
[3, 1, 5]
>>> l_odd.sort(reverse=True)
>>> l_odd
[5, 3, 1]
>>> l_odd[0]
5
```

The trick is filtering out the odd numbers to make l_odd.
Note that sorting requires about N*log(N) operations, where as max() takes only N operations. Also note I used reverse=True. I could have just sorted in normal order and taken l_odd[-1] as you suggested.

The best way to solve this problem:
I suggest you iterate through l_odd in a for loop and keep track of the maximum. (so don't bother sorting).

Try something like this:

```
>>> _max=-99999999
>>> l_odd=[i for i in l if i%2==1]
>>> l_odd
[3, 1, 5]
>>> for i in l_odd:
...     #check if i is bigger than the current _max. If it is, set _max=i
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to separate the problem into subproblems. You can safely ignore every even number, so you have to be able to identify even numbers, you have to ignore numbers that satisfy the condition of being even and on the result - a list of odd numbers - you just have to find the highest number.

So, find or implement...

1. ...a function that checks whether a number is even or not.
2. ...a function that filters a list on a condition.
3. ...a function that finds the highest value in a list.

Once you've done that you just have to combine the three functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `List Comprehension`, you can do something fancy like this (as per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
maxodd = sorted([i for i in range(100) if i % 2 != 0])[-1]
print maxodd
```

Working with a pre-populated list called `mylist`, it would look like this:

```
maxodd = sorted([i for i in mylist if i % 2 != 0])[-1]
print maxodd
```

What we're doing here is grabbing only odd values out of the list (`if i % 2 != 0`), sorting the list (`sorted(list)`), and then grabbing the last item in the list `list[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because another alternative can never hurt, here's a solution that doesn't require sorting the full list:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> mylist = [-10, -11, 4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 3]
>>> heapq.nlargest(1, (x for x in mylist if x%2))
[7]
```

This solution will return an empty list if there are no odd numbers.

Comparing the timings of the heap based solution versus a sort based solution (such as the `highest_odd` function in another answer):

```
>>> import timeit, random
>>> mylist = [random.randint(-10000, 10000) for x in xrange(10000)]
>>> s = 'heapq.nlargest(1, (x for x in mylist if x % 2))'
>>> timeit.timeit(s, 'import heapq\nfrom __main__ import mylist', number = 1000)
5.355861186981201
>>>
>>> s = 'highest_odd(mylist)'
>>> timeit.timeit(s, 'from __main__ import mylist, highest_odd', number = 1000)
11.078870058059692
```

One can see that avoiding sorting the list saves considerable time.

Of course, in a real world situation one would use the `max(...)` function:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(s, 'from __main__ import mylist', number = 1000)
4.979420900344849
```

For completeness, here's the actual algorithm the `nlargest(...)` function is using, cut down to its bare essentials:

```
>>> def heap_largest(iterable):
...     it = iter(iterable)
...     result = [it.next()]
...     for e in it:
...         heapq.heappushpop(result, e)
...     return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar more basic assignment like yours. I'm taking a python course. But to just add some simplicity to this question. I'll include my very basic solution that is outside of a function that checks 3 vars and reports the largest odd number. This is a problem in the book Computational programming using python, pg 16.

```
x = 120
y = 77
z = 157

if x%2==1 and x > y and x > z:
    print 'x is greatest odd value'
elif y%2==1 and y > x and y > z:
     print 'y is greatest odd value'
elif z%2==1 and z > x and z > y:
     print 'z is greatest odd value'
else:
    print 'None of these values are odd'
```

Answer (score 0):

@dotcomken:
in this particular example, you are comparing x, y and z even if some of these variables are even numbers. Therefore, if you assign these values for example:
    x = 68
    y = 5
    z = 25
- the program will produce incorrect output (x is your highest number, but it's even, so none of the conditions are met)
I solved this same problem by including a second variable for the odd numbers (see below).

```
x=4
y=17
z=25
x1=0
y1=0
z1=0
if x%2!=0:
    x1=x
if y%2!=0:
    y1=y
if z%2!=0:
    z1=z
elif x%2==0 and y%2==0 and z%2==0:
    print 'all numbers are even'
if x1>y1 and x1>z1:
    print x1
if y1>x1 and y1>z1:
    print y1
if z1>x1 and z1>y1:
    print z1
```

Answer (score 0):

with 3 inputs.

```
#getting inputs
x = int(input("x: "))
y = int(input("y: "))
z = int(input("z: "))
print("\n")

# comparing
if x > z and y > z:
    if (x > y):
        if(x%2 != 0):
             print(x)
        elif(y%2 != 0):
            print(y)
        elif(z%2 != 0):
            print(z)  
        else:
            print("All are even")
if (x > y and z > y):
    if (x > z):
        if (x%2 != 0):
            print(x)
        elif (z%2 != 0):
            print(z)
        elif (y %2 != 0):
            print(y)
        else:
            print("All are even")
if (z > x and y > x):
    if (z > y):
        if (z%2 != 0):
            print(z)
        elif(y%2 != 0):
            print(y)
        elif(x%2 != 0):
            print(x)
        else:
            print("All are even")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recipe:**

1. Filter odd numbers, store in array
2. Sort the odd numbers
3. Return the last element in array

---

```
# list elements
In [1]: x = [12, 35, 42, 54, 68, 7, 8, -23, 0, 23, 567,
                 34, 575, 234, 78, 34, 563, 43]

# store odd numbers
In [2]: odd = []

In [3]: for i in x:
    ...:     if (i%2 !=0):
    ...:         odd.append(i)

# sort list of odd numbers
In [4]: odd.sort()

# slice the last element in the list
In [5]: odd[-1]
Out[5]: 575
```

Answer (score -1):

numbers = []
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter the number: '))
        if num == 0:
            break
        else:
            numbers.append(num)
    except:
        print('Not a valid digit')
odd = [i for i in numbers if i % 2 != 0]
if odd:
    print('The largest odd number is: ', max(odd))
else:
    print('All numbers are even')

Comment: You should try using some formatting so that the code is more readable and clearer to the reader. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help